# Generating Nodes for Tic Tac Toe Tree Minimax

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, nodes

I am trying to create a reverse 4x3 Tic Tac Toe game using a depth first search and Minimax. There's a couple different things wrong with my code right now but on of them is just creating the proper nodes for the tree.

Each of my nodes contains an array called ChildVals which holds the Minimax value for each of the children, and an 4x3 array that holds the board.

I have a variable that counts how many children are in the current node, called childNum, and I have been trying to use that to generate different boards for each of the children. Here is my code for creating the board in my child node:

```
        int openSpace = 0; //counts how many open spaces encountered
        for(int i=0; i < 4; i++){
            for(int j=0; j< 3; j++){
                if(child->board[i][j] == 'X' || child->board[i][j] == 'O'){
                //go to next space
                }
                else{

                    if(openSpace == childNum){
                        if(node->xmove){
                            child->board[i][j] = 'X';
                        }
                        else{
                            child->board[i][j] = 'O';
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        openSpace++;
                    }
                }
                if(openSpace == childNum){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

My thought was for each child number, it would skip that many blank spaces in order to make all the different children. Right now after I generate the first child I get this:

```
|X|| || |
|X|| || |
|X|| || |
|X|| || |
```

When I really wanted this:

```
|X|| || |
| || || |
| || || |
| || || |
```

I know this may seem simple and I'm sorry to seem so dense, but any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` will only break out of the nearest loop. You may need an extra `break` to break out of both loops (if I understand your goal correctly).

Try this, perhaps:

```
for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j< 3; j++) {
        if (child->board[i][j] == 'X' || child->board[i][j] == 'O') {
            //go to next space
        }
        else {
            if (openSpace == childNum) {
                if (node->xmove) {
                     child->board[i][j] = 'X';
                }
                else {
                     child->board[i][j] = 'O';
                }
                break;
            }
            else {
                openSpace++;
            }
        }
        if (openSpace == childNum) {
            break;  // only breaks out of inner loop
        }
    }
    if (openSpace == childNum) {
        break;  // breaks out of outer loop
    }
}
```